# Why use Node.js for scalability?

Tags: node.js

I have an HTTP Server created using Node.js. When it gets a request, it goes to the DB, fetches some data and gives it back to the Response object. The DB call is async and hence a single thread is able to handle a large number of concurrent connections.

But now that means a large number of requests operating concurrently, causing a potential choke at the DB. Though the web server is able to handle concurrent requests, the DB layer is not. Agreed that a DB bottleneck will happen sooner or later as we increase the load and Node.js is not the cause of it. But the question is: Does Node.js have something that postpones the choking? If not, why is a Node.js application known to be scalable?

I have read through the reactor pattern which forms the base of Node.js. It explains only how Node.js as the server is efficient. But the question remains. Any Node.js app would involve a DB and some other resources. While Node.js is efficient, the next layer would still hit the same bottleneck as with any other technology. So why go for Node.js?

Thanks,
Yash

Answer (score 3):

Node is async **IO** with focus on networking. And it is very efficient at that. DB scalability is a different question that has nothing to do with Node itself.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is event-driven and single-threaded.
Yes single-threaded, but a lot of the things you call in node asynchronously - such as network or file I/O.

Its really bad at CPU intensive tasks. But I found a good way of handling exceptional case for CPU intensive tasks to perform on Node, i.e. its better to handle that task through a child process.

I reccommend you to go through the following links for more detailed information:
[Node is single threaded?](http://rickgaribay.net/archive/2012/01/28/node-is-not-single-threaded.aspx)
[Event loops](http://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/basics.html#event-loops)
[Child Process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options)